# When I try to get the user data with Go and firebase adminSDK, I can only get the memory address

Tags: go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm currently using the Firebase adminSDK to get the user data from the firebase authentication.

The following code seems it can access firebase, but the data to be retrieved is a memory address.
I want to get the value.

I tried to find out about this issue, but I couldn't find any clues.
I am happy with any solution or hint.

```
package main

import (
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("/10_pro4_go/workspace/fb.json")
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, opt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error initializing app:", err)
    }

    client, err := app.Auth(ctx)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    //getting all user data
    iter := client.Users(ctx, "")
    fmt.Println(*iter)
    for {
        user, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error listing users: %s\n", err)
        }
        userdata := *user
        log.Printf("read user user: %v\n", userdata)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
2021/01/15 23:08:33 read user user: {0xc00024a000  }
2021/01/15 23:08:33 read user user: {0xc00024a050  }
2021/01/15 23:08:33 read user user: {0xc00024a0f0  }
```

Comment: That looks like struct with one non-nil pointer field and a bunch of other empty fields. Try `log.Printf("read user user: %+v\n", userdata)` to print the field names, or `%#v` to also print the field types. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/F22DYe4cpTd

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The result is as follows.
`2021/01/15 23:55:24 read user user: {UserRecord:0xc0004c4fa0 PasswordHash: PasswordSalt:}`

Comment: Well that's a struct as you can see and you can confirm that by looking at the [docs](https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/auth#ExportedUserRecord). When you have a struct, or a pointer to a struct, you can use [selector expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) to get whichever exported fields you need from that struct.

Answer (score 0):

Accodring to the documentation of firebase auth package `client.Users` returns an Iterator that iterates through `ExportedUserRecord` objects
https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4@v4.6.0/auth#ExportedUserRecord

That `ExportedUserRecord` have an embedded pointer to `UserRecord` which is probably what ur searching for:
https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4@v4.6.0/auth#UserRecord

So i would suggest printing that UserRecord Data, or even UserInfo array inside of it if that is what you goal is:

```
user.UserRecrod.ProviderUserInfo
```